# how to put forget link in input passwordbox?

Tags: html, css

i want to put the link "forget" like this :

[image]

but i am not able achieve this:

i try to change the postion : absolute in css for link

html like this :

```
<div>
                                <input id="txtPassword" type="password" class="textfield password" placeholder="Password" />
                                 <a id="lnkforget" class="hyperlink" style="float: right; margin-right: 5px;">Forgot</a>
                            </div>
```

my demo : http://jsfiddle.net/d0joydmn/

Comment: Don't do that. It makes for a somewhat confusing UI. People are going to be clicking on what looks like the field without paying too much attention and hitting the link by accident. Also 
[the HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: the best is have a link outside the input.

Comment: i Underwood, but somehow i am not able to convince somebody for the same , i must needed UI like this, that's why i came here to get answer for experts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <input id="txtPassword" type="password" class="textfield password" placeholder="Password" />
    <a id="lnkforget" class="hyperlink" style="float: right; margin-right: 5px;position: absolute;top: 7px;right: 0px;">Forgot</a>
</div>
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/d0joydmn/9/)

And in your container `div` `position:relative` and in your `#lnkforget` set `position:absolute` with `right: 0px`.

Also after @quantumwannabe comment:

> you can add padding-right: 55px and box-sizing: border-box to the
>   input element

Comment: there are 2 problem :  [1] - i am not able to click on forget link, for that i wrote the jquery alert, [2] i dont want my password text behind the forget link

Comment: Yes, you can. Check here http://jsfiddle.net/d0joydmn/3/. Don't understant your 2nd issue.

Comment: No, please see this picture : http://oi60.tinypic.com/2ni8kg6.jpg, here, my password dots are behind the forget link.

Comment: Add `padding-right: 55px` and `box-sizing: border-box` to the `input` element. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vsdqf1f/)

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a little bit old, but maybe somebody whil need that.. I have done that with bootstrap 4 like this:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="password" class="form-control border-right-style-none focus-none" placeholder="Password">
    <span class="input-group-addon focus-none" style="background: white; font-size: 80%;">
      <a class="small" href="/password/forgot">Forgot?</a>
    </span>
  </div>
```

and my used css classes:

```
.border-right-style-none {
     border-right-style: none;
}

.border-left-style-none {
    border-left-style: none;
}

.focus-none {
    &:focus {
        -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
        outline: none !important;
        border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## **[Demo:](http://jsfiddle.net/26oq13vn/)**

```
[id=txtPassword]{
    width:200px;
    height:32px;
    border:2px solid red;
    border-radius:4px;
}

[id=txtPassword] +  [id=lnkforget]{
    margin-left:-72px;
    padding:2px 10px;
    background:red;
    transition:margin-left 300ms ease;
    border-radius:4px;
}

[id=txtPassword]:focus +  [id=lnkforget]{
   margin-left:12px; 
}
```

The markup:

```
<input id=txtPassword type=password class="textfield password" placeholder="Password" />
<a id=lnkforget class=hyperlink>Forgot</a>
```